# How do I reload page after session is destroyed?

Tags: javascript, php

Long story short, I need to destroy a session after 5 unsuccessful login attempts and 30 minutes (that's for how long the user is blocked from loggin in) AND then reload the page so that the login form appears again. I am using SESSIONS, and most things work on my site. My form goes away if they reached the limit of login attempts, the SESSION seemingly destroys BUT the page does not reload (I am using javascript for that).

Here's the php code that lives on the page with the form:

```
<?php
include "includes/auth.php";
$_login_count = $_SESSION['login_count'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?

$_show_form = false;

if($_login_count < 5) {
    $_show_form = true;
} else {
    if(isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 30)) {
        // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
        session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
        session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
        header( 'Location: http://localhost:8000/login.php' );
    }
}

$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp

if ($_show_form) {?>
    <div class="loginBox" id="login-box">
        <form id="login-form" action="" method="post" >
            <label for="uname">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="uname" required autofocus/>

            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" required/>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />

        </form>
    </div>
<?}
?>
<script defer src="funcs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my JS func:

```
var checkPage = setInterval(
    function(){
        console.log('Checking page.');
        var isFormThere = document.getElementById('login-box');

        if(isFormThere) {
            console.log('Found form!');
        } else {
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    },
    33000
);
```

I know my if in JS is not exactly how it should be but I am just using it that way to make sure the page is doing what I want it to be doing. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm no sure if I understand correctly. So you want to have the page relaod when the session expires? Can you provide the steps and conditions?

Comment: How long have you been waiting for JS reload? You've got 33 seconds in interval. Try to decrease this value (for example 2000 instead 33000). Or the JS code is not loaded properly. Do you have some errors in console?

Comment: @Łukasz - yes, I've changed the timer to 40 seconds to give it a longer waiting time than the life of a cookie. It now reloads, shows the error message but no form. The second time it reloads after another 40 s (cuz it still doesn't see a form) I get the form on the screen but the error message stays.

Comment: @ChaudPain - no errors in the console. Everything works exactly like I tell it. The problem is I'm not sure what to tell it! ;p YES, I want the page to reload when the session expires. When it expires, the login count resets back to 0 and the page should have the form to login again.

Comment: @VarvaraJones What do you mean by "shows the error message but no form". What is the error message? BTW You can't use header() like this - check documentation. http://php.net/manual/pl/function.header.php Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your time! Your questions led me to thinking and implementing some simpler solution. @Łukasz, I keep forgetting the header  has very specific rules to its implementation so I went for a javascript version of it with window.location = "http://localhost:8000". Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. I'm no php expert, but the javascript function you use is setting up and interval, which means that you will get the callback function called every 33000 milliseconds no matter what happens. So your callback function might not end up being called at the same time your session dies. You could implement a debounce type of function when you don't detect activity for 33000 instead. This or check if the session is alive after every activity is detected. This would be better than a trottle (interval) approach.

Comment: Thanks @ChaudPain! I've figured a simpler solution out than what I originally submitted but your comments are good too and I may look into doing that!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `<? ?>`

is `open_short_tags` enabled on your server?

Otherwise, replace `<? ?>` with `<?php ?>`

Comment: Yes, it's enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in PHP without the JavaScript.

If you send a param back in the header redirect and pick it up on the response, if its there redirect again:

`header('Location: http://localhost:8000/login.php?refresh=true');`

```
if(isset($_GET['refresh']) && $_GET['refresh'] == 'true')
  header('Location: http://localhost:8000/login.php');
```